# How can I detect that AVQueuePlayer finished playing?

Tags: swift, avqueueplayer

I am playing back a queue of multiple audio files using `AVQueuePlayer`. I have not been able to detect that the last audio file finished playback.

For `AVAudioPlayer` there is `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` with `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`, however that seems not to apply to `AVQueuePlayer`.

How do I detect that `AVQueuePlayer` finished playback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to add before inserting an item:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem
```

which then calls

```
@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(sender: Notification) {
    print("Finished playing")
}
```